# Listbox and SqlDataReader Issue

Tags: winforms, ado.net, sqldatareader

I am attempting load employee data from a stored procedure into a `listbox` in a form load event by `ID` and assign each with an image. The code above is what I have thus far. So what I'm trying to do here is to fill the `listview` with data from my data reader.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(
                            @"Data Source=MyPC\Test;Initial Catalog=TEST5;Integrated Security=True");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT emp_first_name FROM Employees", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

listView1.Items.Clear();

while (dr.Read())
{
    ListViewItem recs = new ListViewItem();

    recs.Text = dr["dept_name"].ToString();
    recs.Text = dr["emp_first_name"].ToString();
    recs.Text = dr["emp_last_name"].ToString();
    recs.Text = dr["emp_email"].ToString();
    recs.Text = dr["emp_phone"].ToString();
    recs.Text = dr["emp_position"].ToString();
    recs.Text = dr["emp_address1"].ToString();
    recs.Text = dr["emp_address2"].ToString();
    recs.Text = dr["emp_city"].ToString();
    recs.Text = dr["emp_state"].ToString();
    recs.Text = dr["emp_postal_code"].ToString();

    recs.Tag = dr["empId"].ToString();
    recs.ImageIndex = 0;
    listView1.Items.Add(recs);
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is currently only returning one fieid:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT emp_first_name FROM Employees", conn);
```

I'm guessing you wanted this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Employees", conn);
```

You need to open the connection and close your disposable resources.  Your current code is constantly replacing the `recs.Text` property to the point that the only thing you should see in the list are "emp_postal_code" values.  I *suspect* you are looking for something like this, where you display the user name as the main item of the ListViewItem and then include the other information as SubItems of the item (for when displaying in Detailed view):

```
listView1.Items.Clear();

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(...)) {
  conn.Open();
  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Employees", conn)) {
    using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
      while (dr.Read()) {
        ListViewItem recs = new ListViewItem();

        recs.Text = dr["emp_first_name"].ToString() + " " +
                    dr["emp_last_name"].ToString();

        recs.SubItems.Add(dr["dept_name"].ToString());
        recs.SubItems.Add(dr["emp_email"].ToString());
        etc...

        recs.Tag = dr["empId"].ToString();
        recs.ImageIndex = 0;
        listView1.Items.Add(recs);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried that. Is there a property to set to all the listview to display it's contents on load?

Comment: @JodieThatOneGuyLogan As Joel mention's in his answer, the connection isn't open.  You never documented what the problem was-- is there an error? What result are you seeing that you weren't expecting?

Comment: Sorry for the late response... What I am attempting to do is to to load the data from my employee table into a data reader, display the results in a listview with clickable images for each record so that when the record is clicked, the details will be displayed on a separate form.

Comment: Added the database connection. I didn't get an error or any results

Comment: Thanks for your help. You are pointing me into the right direction but the form is still blank.

Comment: @JodieThatOneGuyLogan If it's blank, make sure you know how many records you are getting.  Place a debug stop in the code and walk through it line by line as the code runs.

Comment: @JodieThatOneGuyLogan I see that you unchecked it as the answer.  Is there something more you need?

Answer (score 0):

I see several things here:

1. You never open the connection:
2. You reference a number of fields in the reader that are not included in your statement's select clause.
3. You overwrite, rather than append to, the text property of your ListViewItem, so that only the last assigned property value will show.